# Jquery select box ignore if class present

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-1.0

I have this code for a filter button that replaces the string in the button based on what is selected:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li', function (event) { // Filter Select replacement

    var $target = $(event.currentTarget);

    $target.closest('.btn-group')
       .find('[data-bind="label"]').text($target.text())
          .end()
       .children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');

    return false;

});
```

However, I want it to ignore label headers(I use a css class)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle form-control pos-abs" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span data-bind="label">Filter</span> <span class="caret"></span> <!--Filter for Stock Watch-->
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Suppliers</li>
        <li><a href="#">Fictional Supplier</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fictional Supplier 2</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Stock</li>
        <li><a href="#">Ok</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Low Stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suspended</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Shipment</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using a boostrap framework, and using ASP.Net Core framework to build the application. It is currently only on Local Machine.

Any idea how to modify the Jquery code to ignore if a  specified class(.dropdown-header) is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

#### Using [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

**(note that you'll want to avoid `.divider` as well):**

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li:not(.dropdown-header, .divider)', function (event) {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li:not(.dropdown-header, .divider)', function (event) {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle form-control pos-abs" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span data-bind="label">Filter</span> <span class="caret"></span> <!--Filter for Stock Watch-->
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Suppliers</li>
        <li><a href="#">Fictional Supplier</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fictional Supplier 2</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Stock</li>
        <li><a href="#">Ok</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Low Stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suspended</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Shipment</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### Using [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li:has(a)', function (event) {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li:has(a)', function (event) {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle form-control pos-abs" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span data-bind="label">Filter</span> <span class="caret"></span> <!--Filter for Stock Watch-->
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Suppliers</li>
        <li><a href="#">Fictional Supplier</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fictional Supplier 2</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Stock</li>
        <li><a href="#">Ok</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Low Stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suspended</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Shipment</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the job, Thanks!

Comment: @Zaeo happy to help, note my update about `.divider` :)

Comment: Nice catch :) Applied it to divider too.